# Dispatching a Function Defined in Another Substrate FRAME Pallet

Tags: substrate

I am familiar with one mechanism for achieving the goal described in this question's title: passing a dispatchable call, which is written in its own pallet, as an argument when invoking an extrinsic that is written in another pallet, as in the Sudo pallet or the multi-sig capabilities defined in the Utility pallet. What are the other options for dispatching functions across pallets? To be specific, I would like to include a pallet, Pallet A, as `Trait`-bound type for another pallet, Pallet B, and then dispatch a function that is defined in Pallet B from within Pallet A.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The behavior of dispatching calls like the Utility or Sudo pallet only makes sense when you need to control the origin/filters to a truly arbitrary dispatchable function.

If you have two specific pallets that want to interact with one another, using a Trait to couple them is the correct approach. You can see this behavior in Substrate master by looking at the `ChangeMembers` trait and how it is used across pallets like Collective, Membership, Society, Phragmen Elections, etc...

Additionally, you can look at a much bigger trait like `Currency` and see that it basically exposes the `transfer` "extrinsic" through `Currency::transfer`, allowing any pallet to execute this function in its own context.

So in summary:

- Would recommend you move forward with a trait
- Would not recommend you use `call.dispatch` for such a specific pallet to pallet interaction